# Sequence construction in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

What I am trying to do is that, starting from two sequences of bytes (let's call it s1 and s2), I want to obtain the sequence d, representing the maximum of each position.

I've tried to move the sequence s1 in destination, so that afterwards I could compare the sequence s2 with the new destination sequence and just replace the elements when needed.

So.. the "movement" is done, it's just that it doesn't do its job - it doesn't replace anything.

Any suggestion is welcomed. :D

```
;S1: 1, 3, 6, 2, 3, 7
;S2: 6, 3, 8, 1, 2, 5
;D: 6, 3, 8, 2, 3, 7

ASSUME cs:text_,ds:data_

data_ SEGMENT

s1 db '1362375'
l equ $-s1
s2 db '6381259' 
d db l dup (?)

data_ ENDS

text_ SEGMENT
start:
mov ax, data_
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov si, offset s1
mov di, offset d
mov cx, l
cld
rep movsb
push si 
mov si, offset s2 
Repeta:
  cld
  lodsb
  repne scasb
  jg Instruct
  Instruct:
    stosb
loop Repeta
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
text_ ENDS
end start
```

Comment: Comment your code, especially if you want others to help. It's for example unclear why you even have a `scasb` in there if you want to compare each position only? Also, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: as a beginner, I thought that was necessary. this is why I asked this question, to see if I misunderstood things. also, sorry for not commenting the code, will do that next time

Comment: Commenting the code is even more important for **you**! In six months time when you revisit the project, will you be able to recall the *purpose* of the coding?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError it's copying the whole array, that's a letter `l` (for "length") not a digit `1`.

Comment: Use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47400609/edit) and add the comments. Also describe the algorithm you try to use, possibly as C or pseudocode. The recommendation to use a debugger still stands of course.

Comment: to be honest, I don't really have an idea how to describe it in pseudocode.. the idea would be the following: I put in "si" the starting sequence, in "di" the destination one.. oh, yes, and in "cx" the length. afterwards I moved from and in "di" the first sequence, freed up and put the second sequence instead. and the idea was to compare the current sequence with the one in "di". i really hope this makes some sense

Comment: The comments should be in the code itself, not in divorced comment boxes. Use comments to explain the *intent* of the line. Don't use them to explain what can be found in the processor or assembler manual, unless it is a relevant point that might be missed.

Comment: don't describe in pseudocode particular registers or instructions, but your intent... your code roughly reminds me of this idea: 1) copy s1 sequence to d 2) compare s2 sequence against d, overwrite smaller values  ... this can be then broken down into more finer steps, like the second step requiring loop, etc... Then I would start to look for particular instructions. I would probably refrain from this idea and from string instructions, and use standard `mov/cmp/mov` reading both `s1` and `s2` at the same time, but if you want to follow original idea, rather check `cmpsb`, than `scasb`.

Comment: And after you have the intents commented, try to re-read the instructions with fresh mind state, like you see them first time, and try to figure out if they follow your intent, what they will do when executed. Validate that against the instruction reference guide. Of course it's much easier to verify that in debugger, that each instruction works as you expect, but for some weird reason you refuse the simple way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting hung up on using x86 string instructions and treating these as strings.  The problem you're trying to solve has nothing to do with strings.

The fact that the arrays of bytes you're operating on are ASCII codes for digits is not relevant or useful (except that the ASCII codes for `'0'` through `'9'` are contiguous and in order, so you can skip the step of converting the digits to integers).

The problem you need to solve is a simple per-element max, like this

```
for (unsigned i=0 ; i<size ; i++)
    d[i] = max(S1[i], S2[i]);
```

Your values (ASCII codes) are all less than 127, so you can use signed or unsigned comparison, whichever is more convenient.

Notice that the result for `d[i]` only depends on `S1[i]` and `S2[i]`, not on any earlier or later bytes in any string.  Once you realize this, it should be straightforward to implement (and you should see that `repne scasb` (string-search, i.e. `strchr`) is not useful).

You could copy one array to the destination separately from the loop, but x86 has enough registers that this isn't necessary, especially with static data so you don't need to keep 3 pointers in registers, just an index.  (But you *could* keep 3 pointers in registers if you wanted, using `bx`, `si`, and `di`).  It's simple and efficient to just read from the two sources and store the max to the right position in `d` on each iteration.  (You can use `stosb` for that, and `lodsb` for the load from one of the two source arrays if you like.)

**Your current code is actually close to working (I think), but use `scasb` instead of `repne scasb`**.  Also, `scasb` and `stosb` both increment `di`, so what you really want is a conditional `mov [di-1], al`.  (The instruction that increments `di` can't be conditional.)  Also, the branch target needs to be *after* the instruction you want to skip.

You don't need `cld` inside the loop.  Just do it once before `rep movsb`.  Also, single-step your code with a debugger to get the loop count right for the loop.

---

BTW, in SIMD terminology, we call this a "vertical" operation, as opposed to "horizontal" (where you have to shuffle within a 16B vector of data to e.g add neighbouring elements together).

Another recent question asked about the exact same problem, with the same data, but with 32-bit code.  [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47319258/224132) there shows how to use [SSE2 `pmaxub`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PMAXUB.html) to do pairwise-max operations on two vectors of 16 unsigned bytes in parallel, and then store the first 6 bytes of results into `[d]`.  8086 of course doesn't support SSE2 instructions, but modern CPUs in 16-bit real mode do.